# vbscript server side validation

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Basically I have a page named `dvds.asp` with a form that goes to `action="process.asp"`. The `process.asp` script validates the `Name`, `Surname` and `Email` fields. I would like that if the email does not exist, a redirect will occur to the original page (`dvd.asp`) and also display a custom error.

The validation of the email field and redirect I know how to do. The only problem is how I am going to get the custom error value in the `dvds.asp`.

Any help please? :)

**FYI:**

I am using this code in `process.asp` to validate:

```
if txtEmail = "" then
Server.Transfer(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER"))
else
```

Now  the error I want to show on the `dvds.asp` page is: "Please fill in your email" .. How I can do that please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing any source, (For instance, how are you validating the email? What is this "Custom error value"?

Assuming you have a function that validates the email and returns false if it fails and the matching error value is "1" then you could simply include this in your redirect:

```vb
Dim EmailAddress
EmailAddress = Request.Form("EmailAddress")
If ValidateEmail(EmailAddress) = False Then
    Response.Redirect("dvd.asp?ErrorID=1")
End If
```

and on the Origional Source page, you could just display errors back to the user as follows:

```vb
   '#### Output errors
    If Trim(Request.QueryString("ErrorID")) <> "" Then
        Select Case Request.QueryString("ErrorID")
            Case "1" ' #### Email Error
                Response.Write("<p><span style=""color: red"">Error: Invalid email address</span></p>")
            Case "2" ' #### Bad Name
                Response.Write("<p><span style=""color: red"">Error: Invalid Name</span></p>")
            Case Else
                Response.Write("<p><span style=""color: red"">Error: Unknown / Generic Error</span></p>")
        End Select
    End If
```

One small suggestion by the way, its often preferable for pages such as this to post to the same page and include any email functionality you need from a class / SSI. That way you cold auto-populate the form again if an error occurred rather than expecting your end user to re-type the whole form if they get an error.

Comment: I am using this code in process.asp to validate:

if txtEmail = "" then
Server.Transfer(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER"))
else

Now  the error i want to show on  the dvds.asp page is: "Please fill in your email" .. How I can do that please?

Comment: Check if HTTP_REFERER contains querystrings, if it does, append "&ErrorID=1", if it does not, append "?ErrorID=1", eg: Server.Transfer(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") & "ErrorID=1") - note that the original page will need to detect the ErrorID value and display the relevant message.

Comment: Yes and that was my question :) how the original page ios going to get the original error message please.

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly, although please note my comment at the bottom regarding your overall approach.